# WCF service hosted in a Managed Windows Service can not be accessed from another machine

Tags: wcf, service

I have a WCF servise hosted in a Managed Windows Service that I developed according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) manual. In App.config I specified the following:

```
 <service name="Inpas.Unipos.LicenseManager.SamService.Service"
           behaviorConfiguration="SamServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/SamService/service"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="Inpas.Unipos.LicenseManager.SamService.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

In a client I connect to service this way:

```
public void ConnectToService(string host, string port)
{
    var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/SamService/service", host, port));
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, endpoint);
    _client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    _client.Get2X2();
}
```

In a local machine it works fine, but if I try to connect to service from another machine - I get an exception:

*EndpointNotFoundException
Message: There was no endpoint listening at http://10.xx.xx.xx:8000/SamService/service that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to see  the service IE from a different box?

Comment: @Dhawalk what is box? how to check that?

Comment: Are you using `http://localhost:8000/SamService/service` as the address for the **service** on the different machine?  If so, you need to change the address to the machine name (or domain name) (like http://www.mydomain.com/" - localhost only refers to the machine the program is running on.

Comment: i mean a different machine?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by opening the inbound port for the service:

- Open Windows Firewall by clicking the Start button , and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type firewall, and then click Windows Firewall.
- In the left pane, click Advanced settings.  If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
- In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialog box, in the left pane, click Inbound Rules, and then, in the right pane, click New Rule.
- Follow the instructions in the New Inbound Rule wizard( select Tcp in the "Protocol and Ports" step of this wizard).